# how to find the number of solutions for $\ln(x) =x^2/8$ using simple math principles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

how to find the number of solutions for  $\ln(x) = x^2/8$ with high school level math (basic logarithm rules or something of that nature)( and without graphing $\ln(x)$ and $x^2/8$). (sorry for the poor formatting, feel free to edit)
I tried to change the equation to someting familiar to use a logarithm rule:
$$\displaylines{
x^2/8 = \ln(x) \cr
x/8^{0.5} = lan(x)^{0.5} \cr
x = 8^{0.5}*lan(x)^{0.5}
}$$
Changing the representation of the equation using the basic logarithm rule
$$\displaylines{
x^2/8 = \ln(x) \cr
x = e^{x^2/8}
}$$
But my tries got me nowhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't solve it with high school math. You can, however, find the _number_ of solutions without actually pinpointing them.

Comment: I want to find the number of real solutions regardless of their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y:=x^2$ (as $x>0$, no solution is introduced). The equation can be written

$$y=e^{y/4}.$$

The exponential is a convex function, so it has at most two intersections with a straight line.

Now as $0<e^{0/4},4>e^{4/4}$ and $12<e^{12/4}$, we have these two intersections.

Comment: thank you for your response. When writing down I got to $e^{y/8} = y^{0.5}$ which is different from what you wrote. could you explain a bit more (please consider I am just out of high school).

Comment: @Noa:  just square.

Comment: Ok, thank you For this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you ar looking the the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\log (x)-\frac{x^2}{8}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{4}$$ cancels at $x=2$ ($x=-2$ being discareded because of the logarithm.
$$f(2)=\log (2)-\frac{1}{2} > 0$$ and $f''(2)=-\frac{1}{2}$. So, $x=2$ is a maximum and there are two solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score -1):

try visualizing the graphs of ln(x) and x^2 / 8. The first is a log-curve, and the second in a parabola. They will  intersect at at most two points. so you will have at most two solutions.

Since the log-curve starts (or ends) at the origin, and the parabola will "circumnavigate" the origin going from -infinity to +infinity, it's safe to say that they will intersect at exactly one point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I am not sure that this complies with the "without graphing" requirement.

Comment: "it's safe to say that they will intersect at exactly one point": you should have read the other answers. (And the log curve does not start at the origin. And a priori nothing guarantees that it meets the parabola at all.)